# R Package to show equations in 'graphic' mode

Tags: r, latex

I'm looking for some R package that lets me output an R formula/equation in a (don't know how to name it..) "graphic" mode, like how it would be shown in apps like Mathtype, Mathcad or similar.

Any ideas? Thx in advance!

PS: Bonus points for a package to convert an r formula to latex formula's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plotmath functionality will add text to a plot and allows for superscripts, subscripts, greek letters, integral signs, etc.  which will give most of what you want.  Type `demo(plotmath)` and `?plotmath` for the demonstration and details.

The `latex` function in the rms package will take various fitted objects and create the LaTeX syntax that will represent the fitted object.

Comment: Yeah, i think plotmath is the only way (other than making a bash/perl parser to convert it to latex) Thanks!